# ORGMODE Exporting to text without wrapping

Tags: org-export

As simple as that. Everytime I export from orgmode to text the lines are wrapped. How to disable this?

Thank you,

E.

Comment: You may try exporting via `ox-pandoc` to plain text. Pandoc includes an `--wrap=none` command line option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John Kitchin initially wrote [a simple program](http://kitchingroup.cheme.cmu.edu/blog/2016/06/16/Copy-formatted-org-mode-text-from-Emacs-to-other-applications/) to do this.  He then improved it and made it into [ox-clip](https://github.com/jkitchin/ox-clip) a org-mode based Emacs package, which is easy to get through Melpa's repository.  Not only does it avoid wrapping text, it also preserves the format on the clipboard so that it is a breeze to paste.

ox-clip may need you to install a clipboard manager depending on your system.  Specific installation instructions can be found [here](https://github.com/jkitchin/ox-clip/blob/master/README.org).

Comment: I don't think this refers to the question, does it? :) My initial question was how to export without line wrapping (rather than copying and pasting formatted text outside Emacs).

Comment: I thought it came close enough to the question and valuable enough to include it. 1) Using ox-clip to copy text actually eliminates all wrapping. It is a very easy way to export text if you want to paste it, say, in an e-mail. (But because it exports it as HTML code, it only works when you are pasting it in places that look for HTML code in the clipboard). 2) The function ox-clip-formatted-copy exports an org region to HTML and copies it to the clipboard.  You need to then paste it where you need to export it.   You may have had a more specific conception of exporting where this did not count.

Comment: Thanks, I think that could work. I did not see the whole extent of the value in your answer. Thumbs up!

Answer (score 3):

Org-mode provides the customization variable `org-ascii-text-width`. If you set this to a large enough value, it has the effect of not wrapping text blocks during export to plain text.

However, doing this also does weird things to text that the exporter tries to present as centered titles and subtitles. That applies to the contents of `#+TITLE:` and `#+AUTHOR:` lines, and probably other similar options. You can turn these off via the customization variables `org-export-with-title` and `org-export-with-author`. I don't see any obvious way of modifying the title formatting in a way that wouldn't get mangled by long lines.

Answer (score 0):

Once in a while, I'm drafting e-mails in an orgmode buffer. I'd like to export the plain text, but without wrapped lines. Usually I forget to disable auto-fill-mode while writing.

So after finishing the text, I copy it into scratch, mark it and then:
`M-x replace-string Ctrl-q Ctrl-j Ctrl-q Ctrl-j RET XXXX RET`. Result: Every new paragraph is replaced by XXXX.

Next step: 
`M-x replace-string Ctrl-q Ctrl-j RET <space> RET` : I'm replacing the single newlines with a singel space.

Next step:
`M-x replace-string XXX RET Ctrl-q Ctrl-j RET` : I'm replacing the XXXX against the former new paragraphs.

Ready for copy and paste.

---

## Edit:

After OP made a comment about the `#+OPTIONS:`, I found that you can write `#+OPTIONS: \n:nil` into the preamble of the org file, which is supposed to toggle whether to preserve line breaks (`org-export-preserve-breaks').

Then -- [thanks](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/34964/2334) to [Tyler](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/users/262/tyler) -- I customized org-ascii-text-width. Set it to 10000 and you don't get a line break. But unfortunately the exporter assumes the pagewidth were that large and pushes the sections and the title _far_far_ away.

Comment: Exporting to text seems to impose hard wrapping, even if the source is not filled to begin with

Comment: @Tyler Maybe, but I just copy and paste the »unwrapped« text.

Comment: Actually, I found the answer: #+OPTIONS: ::  (Toggle fixed-width sections ->>(org-export-with-fixed-width))

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein Sounds good. What exactly is the text after `#+OPTIONS`?

Comment: exactly two colons: ::, as I wrote above.

Comment: Actually it doesn't work now (it stopped working) :( Not sure why.

Comment: @EmmanuelGoldstein I don't think that ever worked. The documentation for `org-export-with-fixed-width` says it's related to monospace font formatting in the org document, not about line breaks in ASCII/Utf8 export modes.